# Receive but not show GCM push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com, google-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to receive a GCM push notification but choose to not show it in the notification bar under certain circumstances? On an incoming push notification, I would like to do a check of whether or not the user is within a specified location or not, and only show the push notification in the notification bar if the user is within this location. I'm using Urban Airship.

Thanks in advance

**Update:**

To clarify: in the Urban Airship intent receiver, I have the onReceive() method, which I *thought* was what I was supposed to modify in order to conditionally show the push notification. However, it seems that this intent is only for showing logging information and I suspect that the real receiving intent is baked into the Urban Airship .jar file as the .class file com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver, which contains the onMessage() method. Since this is not the source code, it seems it would be difficult to modify this part since it is linked to the numerous other components. Does anybody have any idea on how this could be done?

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible: push notifications are information to the device, but on Android they aren't automatically shown. You can choose to not display a notification at all. With Urban Airship you can probably just replace their default receiver with one of your own to prevent it from displaying in the notification area.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought should work. However, even though I comment out all of the code in onReceive() in the Urban Airship intent, I still get the notification. Seems it gets raised elsewhere, perhaps in "com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver" which is added in the manifest file? This is a class file so I won't be able to edit that one I guess? Perhaps this won't work with Urban Airship after all?